# How do change the strings on the list to be printed differently?

Tags: python, automation, autoit, pywinauto

I want made Auto Posting Program.using Python
and
I wanted to upload multiple JPG files using window dialog.
(that site don't working input type="file", only Dragging file and Open to window dialog)

So,
I made List like that

```
[['1.jpg'], ['2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg'], ['7.jpg'], ['8.jpg', '9.jpg']]


new_upload = []
idx = 0
for fileCount in amount:
    upload = []
    for n in range(fileCount):
        upload.append(fileList[idx])
        idx += 1
    new_upload.append(upload)

print(upload2)


new_upload = [['1.jpg', '2.jpg'], ['3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg'], ['9.jpg', '10.jpg'], ['11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg']]
```

after that

```
folderPath = r"F:\test\{0}"
uploadfilePath = (folderPath.format(new_upload[i]))

   
   # USE pywinauto

app["open"]["Edit1"].set_text(uploadfilePath)

   # USE pyautoit

autoit.control_set_text(handle, "Edit1", uploadfilePath)
```

But, The result was terrible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRptr.png)

Plz Loot at the a picture.
I wanted it to be entered like this.
**`new_upload[1]  -->  "1.jpg""2.jpg"`**

But that entered
`new_upload[1] --> ['1.jpg','2.jpg']`

**What should I do to change the way I want it to be inputted?**
I haven't slept in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are problems with your python code.
Please look at the example code below

Here in your list, we have an inner list. I think you are NOT iterating the inner list. So the whole inner list content is written to your UI.

Refer to the below code, We are using `two For loops` to iterate the outer loop and inner loop. So in your code, the print can be replaced with the Pywinauto code to set text into UI

```
new_upload = [['1.jpg', '2.jpg'], ['3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg'], ['9.jpg', '10.jpg'], ['11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg']]
folderPath = r"F:\test\{0}"
for upload in new_upload:
    for load in upload:
        uploadfilePath = (folderPath.format(load))

print(uploadfilePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python string has powerful method `.join()` that you can use for joining the list into string. Example:

```
l = ['2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg']
s = '"' + '" "'.join(l) + '"'
print(s)
# "2.jpg" "3.jpg" "4.jpg" "5.jpg" "6.jpg"
```

For your case this piece of code:

```
upload = []
for n in range(fileCount):
    upload.append(fileList[idx])
    idx += 1
```

can be re-written this way:

```
upload_list = [fileList[i] for i in range(idx, idx + fileCount)]
idx += fileCount
upload = '"' + '" "'.join(upload_list) + '"'
```